# Custom Search Engine on Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, search-engine, zend-lucene

We are building a Social Networking website and there are videos, user profiles and other details on the site. The site is developed using Zend Framework. It needs to develop a Site Search Engine feature on this site. It need to index all data in the website and search against that data.

I checked Sphider but it is not easy to use in Zend Framework. And I tried Sphinx but that needs lot of configuration from Terminal. Next I tried is Zend Lucene Component and it works. But I couldn't  display the Videos or Profile Image on the result set.

Please suggest an easy but powerful method to build a Custom Search Engine inside website built on Zend Framework.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at setting up a [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) search server. It is a Lucene implementation, but scales incredibly well. From my understanding Zend's Lucene implementation, while good for small amounts of data, does not scale well.

There is also a [PECL Solr](http://pecl.php.net/package/solr) extension for easy access from PHP, regardless of framework.